# Blackberry Webworks: strange behavior when closing the keyboard

Tags: javascript, blackberry, blackberry-webworks, virtual-keyboard

when closing the virtual keyboard in blackberry webworks, the page sometimes doesn't use the space of the keyboard anymore, that space is blank.

Is there any way to prevent this bug?

Any help would be appreciated, thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution to this issue myself:

With JS:

```
window.onresize = function(){
    window.scrollTo(0,0);
}
```

Or with jQuery:

```
$(window).resize(function(){
    $(window).scrollTop(0);
});
```

This should prevent the bug...

Answer (score 2):

I would double check that you are using the latest version of the WebWorks SDK available for your platform (Smartphone, Tablet, BB10), as well as using the latest OS on your device. If you're still seeing issues, I'd log this as a bug:
https://www.blackberry.com/jira/secure/Dashboard.jspa

Comment: i checked both of that, thank you, i'm still seeing that issues, and i logged the bug.